# Reverse Tether: Sharing Raspberry pi's Internet connection to Android via Bluetooth or USB

Tags: networking, bluetooth, internet

I've seen a bunch of stuff where a phone provides internet to pi, but I was wondering the feasibility of the other way around, where the pi is connected via Bluetooth (or USB) to an android device which shares the pi's interneconnection?

I've tried just connecting via `bluetoothctl`, but that didn't work (unsurprisingly).

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: The same question is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/928845/share-wi-fi-internet-access-via-bluetooth-on-raspberry-pi). Unfortunately, no answer. Also, if you are using Raspbian with GUI (not headless), this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320428/how-can-i-share-my-wifi-connection-through-bluetooth) might be helpful with an installation of `blueman`.

Comment: Please explain why you can't simply set up a wireless AP on the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This answer does not endorse any software company or it's
software. I am just a user of the following suggested program and nothing else.

There is a program called [gnirehtet](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet.git) to reverse tethering for Android.
I have used it in Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. First, go to [release page](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet/releases).
Download the gnirehtet-rust-linux64 ZIP file. Extract the APK file from it and
install it in the Android device (>= 5.0).

That official release page does not provide the ARM version which is required
for Raspberry Pi. I have compiled the ARM versions which can be
[downloaded here](https://github.com/Biswa96/gnirehtet-miui/releases). Copy it in Raspberry Pi. The program also requires ADB
(Android Debug Bridge) i.e. `android-tools-adb` package for Raspbian. Now run
`gnirehtet start; gnirehtet relay` to start reverse tethering. More usage details
can be found in the [release page](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet/blob/master/README.md). There are some issues ([#46](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet/issues/46), [#256](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet/issues/256))
that may be related with this topic.

Comment: apologies for the late response and if im missing something, but what should I be doing with the arm version once its on my Pi? I can't run it even after permission changes.

Comment: @BenjaminFasick OK, I'll edit the answer with more details. Basically, the project readme file has extensive details.